# Bootstrap image and background color outside container

Tags: html, css, containers

I have a website with a Bootstrap container. The problem here is: the background color and image are full-width. With a fluid container. Important is that content which is in a container, is always align with the background color and image.

[image: Example of the design]

I tried something like a absolute fixed container and center it and with a fluid container on the background, but it's not aligned with the images an background color on different screen sizes.

```css
.left {
  background: red;
}
.left:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: inherit;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100vw;
}
.right {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/Mount_Everest_as_seen_from_Drukair2_PLW_edit.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 left">
      <p>
        Banner information here
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right">
      <p>
        The text should always align with the left side of the image. On all screens.<br /><br />
        But the images needs to be full width, just like the red background color which is outside the container with the : before tag.
      </p>    
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Visual example of the JSFiddle]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: See my JSFiddle, please.